# Why my code showing error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown at bw.write(s);

Tags: java, ioexception, bufferedwriter

> Problem Statement: Given an array of integers, answer queries of the form: [i, j] : Print the sum of array elements from A[i] to A[j], both inclusive

This is the code I used:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        long arr[]=new long[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            arr[i]=sc.nextLong();
        long farr[]=new long[n];
        farr[0]=arr[0];
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
            farr[i]=farr[i-1]+arr[i];
        int q=sc.nextInt();
        while(q-->0){
            int i=sc.nextInt();
            int j=sc.nextInt();
            if(i!=0){
                //I'm converting long value to String bcoz bw can't write long value in buffer 
                String s=String.valueOf(farr[j]-farr[i-1]);
                bw.write(s);
            }
            else{
                String s=String.valueOf(farr[j]);
                bw.write(s);
            }
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
}
```

I tried the above code for Sum of Subarray problem

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. This is a compiler error, not an exception, and it is displayed, or printed, or shown. Not 'thrown'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an exception to the method signature.

**public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException**